# Right place to place db checks in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, model-view-controller, express

I'm building an app with NodeJS and ExpressJS.
My folder structure looks like this:

```
/app
    /controllers
    /models
```

And I'm trying to separate all the logic and db calls in the model and the "usertomodel" actions in the controller.
In the controller I have the following code: (in the controller)

```
app.post('/api/nodes/upload/image', processMultipartForm, function(req, res) {

    if (!req.files.file) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            message: 'INVALID_FILE'
        });
    }

    ...

    if (ALLOWED_FORMATS.indexOf(file.mimetype) == -1) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            message: 'INVALID_FILE_FORMAT'
        });
    }

    .....

    NodesModel.createFile({
      ...
    }, {...}, function(){...});
```

To do the simple checks.
But after I finish with all the validation I need to do like 3 asynchronous DB calls (for example to check if the file exists, permissions, etc) and I'm using the waterfall module from `async` npm package in the model and it looks like this: (in the model)

```
NodesSchema.statics.createFile = function(opts, user, cb) {
    var _this = this;

    async.waterfall([
        function(callback) {
            _this.findOne({
                _id: opts.location
            }, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                    return callback('INTERNAL_ERROR');
                }

                if (!data) {
                    return callback('INVALID_LOCATION');
                }

                callback(null, opts.location);
            });
        },
        function(location, callback) {

            _this.findOne({
                location: location,
                owner: user._id,
                name: opts.name,
                isFile: false
            }, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                    return callback('INTERNAL_ERROR');
                }

                if (data) {
                    return callback('FILE_EXISTS');
                }

                callback(null);
            });
        },
```

My questions are:

- Am I doing this right?
- Should I place the "waterfall" in the controller or it should stay in the model?
- Is there a better way of doing these checks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, firstly, regarding your checks -- you are doing those properly. Since all of your checks (from what I can tell), are just checking static values -- they must be executed synchronously, so you're perfect.

Regarding your DB calls -- yes, using the waterfall method is perfect for your use case -- but regarding where to put that logic -- I'm a bit confused as I can't tell what is happening per-say by reading the source.

If your `createFile` method works off a model, I suggest putting that code into your models -- the general MVC rule is to keep your abstracts really clear -- isolate all data-related code in your model, and keep your controllers as pure as possible.